# Information about Kalman Filter

Tags: regression, kalman-filter, state-space-models

I was intending to develop a paper work using Kalman Filter, but I have a few questions about this subject:

1. What are the main differences between a simple AR Model and Kalman Filter? Would it be at the state equation? Because at the observation equation, we do the same kind of parameter estimation, don't we? If I was not right, what is the Kalman Filter benefit for parameter estimation?
2. And between Dynamic Regression and Kalman Filter?
3. What are the main advantages and disadvantages from Kalman Filter?

Comment: An autoregressive (AR) model is a time series model and the Kalman filter is an algorithm with several applications. They are not the same kind of tool or method, I don't see a straightforward way to compare them. _What is the Kalman Filter benefit for parameter estimation?_ When an AR model is written in state-space form, the Kalman filter can be employed to evaluate the likelihood function. Thus, although it wans't its primary application, the Kalman filter turns out to be a convenient tool to obtain parameter estimates by maximum likelihood, as has been pointed in the answer by F. Tusell.

Comment: You are right, I understood that Kalman Filter is an algorithm, but I was thinking about State Space Models (Kalman Filter algorithm) and AR Model. AR Model parameter estimation is based on the total data amount for all period, isn't it? And the State Space/Kalman Filter is based only at the last observation, isn't it?

Comment: Your comment is not clear to me. It seems you are comparing two methods to estimate the parameters of an AR model, what methods are those?

Comment: My final objective is that I have a set of observations. At recent moments, two/three years before, these observations are varying over a huge range. And I need to forecast next periods. Nowadays, I am using VAR/VEC or ARIMA Models, but I was learning about State Space Forms and Kalman Filter that could help me to forecast better. I would like to understand better about Kalman Filter and explain what are the differences between SS Form/Kalman Filter estimation and others. After this, I wanna try to forecast using Kalman Filter algorithm and compare with my models. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Your question is too broad. The Kalman filter is not by itself a forecasting tool. The filter operates on an 
underlying model. In principle, the Kalman filter can be applied with any Gaussian linear model defined in a state-space form. This includes a wide range of models, 
ARIMA models, structural time series models, dynamic regression models,... Saying that you want to use the Kalman filter to obtain forecasts is a very broad statement and makes it difficult to give you any further feedback.

Comment: One of the questions that I have is: VAR or ARIMA models use the full set of observations to estimate the parameters , while the SS / Kalman filter uses only the latest data available to estimate the current setting, is it?

Comment: VAR or ARIMA are not methods to estimate the parameters of a model, so saying that they _use the full set of observations to estimate the parameters_ does not make sense to me. An answer to your comment would take a lot of space and it seems it would require fixing some concepts and ideas. I recommend you to read some textbook or online documentation about time series models, maximum likelihood and the Kalman filter.

Comment: Ok, I say that parameters estimation would be OLS or loglikelihood, as example, wouldn't be? But I was talking about linear relation between models. VAR as an example of all endogenous variables and ARIMA as independent variable and dependent variables. The parameters that we obtain with VAR or ARIMA are the mean over all set of observations, right? And what textbook would you recommend about Kalman Filter?

Comment: You may be interested in the references given in [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116079/standard-model-for-time-series-with-possibly-multiple-seasonal-component/116167#116167).

Comment: Dear javlacalle, could you give me these references?

Comment: Go to this link that I mentioned in the previous comment: [http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116079/standard-model-for-time-series-with-possibly-multiple-seasonal-component/116167#116167](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116079/standard-model-for-time-series-with-possibly-multiple-seasonal-component/116167#116167).

Answer (score 4):

You can cast and AR model in state-space form (and an ARMA model, or dynamic regression model). The Kalman filter is an algorithm that enables you to recursively compute the state vector (and the likelihood, with normal data):
thus, it indirectly provides a way to maximize the likelihood.

Comment: +1. In fact, R's `arima` function uses a state-space model under the hood. Poke into the data structure returned by `arima` and you'll see it.